# OSGi NoClassDefFoundError when running outside of Eclipse with my Bundle

Tags: eclipse, export, osgi, bundle, noclassdeffounderror

I have an application made up of multiple bundles. Inside eclipse it is working perfectly. When I export it as a product it was working perfect but something has changed and I can't work out what.

Now when I export my bundles, at runtime I get NoClassDefFoundError. The Error is in one of my bundle's activator and the class it is unable to find is in another bundle. A common bundle.

When I try to start the bundle I get the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ardor/common/util/Systems
```

This class is in another one of my bundles com.ardor.common.
At the console when I inspect this bundle with the "bundle" command I get

```
Exported packages
com.ardor.common.util; version="0.0.0"[exported]
```

I'm stuck for ideas :(

Comment: Coding at midnight comes with added difficulties. It seems that the problem is that my exported bundle jars have a manifest but actually no class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to remove compiler warnings I removed from the build.properties

output.. = bin/

with out this the bundle contains no class files

**build.properties**

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
.
```